# Creating an Alias on update with sql server vs mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I have this query that perfectly does what I want in mysql:

```
update st t1, (SELECT ref, u_peso, 
                (select u_peso from st
where st.ref=sc.refb) 
 as pesoaassumir, sc.refb 
 FROM st inner join sc
on st.ref=sc.ref) t2 
 set t1.u_peso = t2.pesoaassumir
  where t1.ref=t2.ref
```

I tried to use it in SQL server and it gives me an error near t1 and t2.
I did some research and find out that alias on sql server are not called in the beginning and on the inner and from section I tried to change but I am having no luck.

For example:

```
update t1, (SELECT ref, u_peso, (select u_peso from st where st.ref=sc.refb)
as pesoaassumir, sc.refb FROM st t1 inner join sc t2 on st.ref=sc.ref) 
set t1.u_peso = t2.pesoaassumir
where t1.ref=t2.ref
```

this one gives me: `Incorrect syntax near ','. LINE 1`. It is the very first comma.

If I did not make myself clear sorry

(OLD POST BELOW)

---

```
 update st t1, (SELECT ref, u_peso, 
                    (select u_peso from st
    where st.ref=sc.refb) 
     as pesoaassumir, sc.refb 
     FROM st inner join sc
    on st.ref=sc.ref) t2 
     set t1.u_peso = t2.pesoaassumir
      where t1.ref=t2.ref
```

I also tried this way:

```
update t1, (SELECT ref, u_peso, 
                    (select u_peso from st t1
    where t1.ref=t2.refb) 
     as pesoaassumir, t2.refb 
     FROM t1 inner join sc t2
    on t1.ref=t2.ref) 
     set t1.u_peso = t2.pesoaassumir
      where t1.ref=t2.ref
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong and I know you can figure this out in one minute:

(edit) heres what I am trying to do

I have 2 tables

I cant post images yet remove spaces
 [image: image1]
  [image: image2]

I want to copy the field peso from the second one for the items that are related on the 1st table

example

I have

```
table                      table
          u_peso       |
item      0.50         |    item   item ew
item ew    null        |    item   item qw
item qw    null        |
```

the items are related in the second table? so they will adquire the 0.50

```
table                      table
          u_peso       |
item      0.50         |    item   item ew
item ew   0.50         |    item   item qw
item qw   0.50         |
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to do here? It looks like you are trying to update the u_peso column to the same value it already is. I don't think that is what you are really trying to do though. The syntax is certainly all wrong but once we understand your objective we can help with the syntax.

Comment: sorry then i will update you then right away

Comment: Screenshots of your application are not going to help much. You need to provide ddl and sample data in addition to what you want to accomplish. sqlfiddle.com is a good place to post this. You might also take a look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Hello! The thing is, i Used this exact code on mysql and it perfectly does what i want, i just want to know how to call the alias correctly on sql server

Comment: I am not a mysql expert but that code looks like gibberish to me. I can't begin to help you determine how to do this in t-sql because I still have no idea what your tables are like or what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL-Server you can do something like this:

[UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

```
update tp2
set
    u_peso = tp.upeso
from st tp
inner join table_peso_rel rel on
    rel.refA = tp.ref
inner join st tp2 on
    tp2.ref = rel.refB
```

Not sure if this is 100% correct, your tables aren't very clear..